# Ajax JSON Request fails

Tags: jquery, json, rest

I created a simple rest service which serves me JSONs. I can access it trough the browser via `http://localhost:8080/WebTodo/rest/todos` and get a list with ToDos in JSON. (It was this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html#crud)

Now I want to get the JSONs via Jquery using this simple html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
   <script>

function getJsonFunc() {
       console.log("find all");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/WebTodo/rest/todos",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
          success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            alert('Success')
         },
          error: function (jqXHR, status) {
          alert('Error')
         }
    });
   }

   function writeJson(todo) {

              console.log("after json");
                var items = [];
                $.each( todo, function( key, val ) {
                items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
                });
                $( "<ul/>", {
                "class": "my-new-list",
                html: items.join( "" )
                }).appendTo( "body" );


   }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
      <button id="search" onClick="getJsonFunc()">get</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This always returns me the Error alert. I already tried with different browsers and also disabled the same origin policy in Chrome to try it. Nothing helped. What am I missing here?

This is the acutal json which I receive in the browser `{"todo":[{"description":"Description","done":"false","titel":"Do something","uri":"2"},{"description":"Description","done":"false","titel":"Learn REST","uri":"1"}]}`

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: replace alert('Error') with alert(jqXHR.responseText); and check.

Comment: It executes `error: function (jqXHR, status) {
          alert('Error')
         }`
I don't see an actual error message

Comment: alert(jqXHR.responseText) is empty

Comment: in chrome press F12 to see error, then please write here?

Comment: Is the page running the script also on `http://localhost:8080/`? How did you attempt to disable the SOP in Chrome?

Comment: check chrome dev tools network tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it looks like SOP is the problem.
I tried to disable it in chrome with --disable-web-security.

I now run the html file and rest on the same webserver and it works.

Comment: Found this blog post about cross domain filtering for jersey, very useful: http://simplapi.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/jersey-jax-rs-implements-a-cross-domain-filter/